# How to register an HttpModule outside of the web server environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, httpmodule

I want to test a controller method (ASP.NET MVC 4) that uses some HttpModule at some point like this:

```
 var sessionToken = CreateSessionSecurityToken(CreatePrincipal(claims.ToList()), isPersistent);
            FederatedAuthentication.**SessionAuthenticationModule**.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
```

The module is a subclass of the SessionAuthenticationModule. I have in the app.config file of the test assembly the necessary configurations:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="FormsSessionAuthentication" type="Security.FormsSessionAuthenticationModule, Security"/>
      <!--<add name="SessionAuthenticationModule"
           type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />-->
    </httpModules>
...

 <system.webServer>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="FormsSessionAuthentication" type="Security.FormsSessionAuthenticationModule, Security"/>
      <!--<add name="SessionAuthenticationModule"
           type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />-->
    </modules>
```

This is what I am trying to do from a unit test context:

```
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance = new HttpApplication();
            HttpApplication.RegisterModule(typeof (FormsSessionAuthenticationModule));
            Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(FormsSessionAuthenticationModule));

            var modules = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules;
```

The `modules` collection is empty after I try to register it using the above two methods.

Any ideas?

EDIT - Added httpModule implementation

```
public class FormsSessionAuthenticationModule : SessionAuthenticationModule
{
    protected bool IsSlidingExpiration { get; set; }
    protected TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }
    protected string LoginUrl { get; set; }
    protected string CookieName { get; set; }
    protected string CookieDomain { get; set; }
    protected bool RequireSsl { get; set; }
    protected bool CachePrincipalOnServer { get; set; }

    protected override void InitializeModule(HttpApplication context)
    {
        base.InitializeModule(context);

        context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
    }

    protected override void InitializePropertiesFromConfiguration()
    {
        base.InitializePropertiesFromConfiguration();

        // read formsauth configuration
        IsSlidingExpiration = FormsAuthentication.SlidingExpiration;
        Timeout = FormsAuthentication.Timeout;
        LoginUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl;
        CookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        CookieDomain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
        RequireSsl = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL;

        // read other configuration
        CachePrincipalOnServer = false;
        bool enabled;
        if (bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CachePrincipalOnServer"], out enabled))
        {
            CachePrincipalOnServer = enabled;
        }

        // configure cookie handler
        CookieHandler.Name = CookieName;
        CookieHandler.Domain = CookieDomain;
        CookieHandler.RequireSsl = RequireSsl;
    }

    protected override void OnSessionSecurityTokenReceived(SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSessionSecurityTokenReceived(e);

        if (IsSlidingExpiration)
        {
            if (NeedsRenew(e.SessionToken))
            {
                e.SessionToken = CreateSessionSecurityToken(
                    e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal,
                    e.SessionToken.Context,
                    DateTime.UtcNow,
                    DateTime.UtcNow.Add(Timeout),
                    e.SessionToken.IsPersistent);

                e.SessionToken.IsReferenceMode = CachePrincipalOnServer;
                e.ReissueCookie = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var httpApplication = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (httpApplication != null)
        {
            var context = httpApplication.Context;

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                var noRedirect = context.Items["NoRedirect"];

                if (noRedirect == null)
                {
                    var loginUrl = LoginUrl + "?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.RawUrl, context.Request.ContentEncoding);
                    context.Response.Redirect(loginUrl);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual bool NeedsRenew(SessionSecurityToken token)
    {
        DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

        TimeSpan span = utcNow - token.ValidFrom;
        TimeSpan span2 = token.ValidTo - utcNow;

        if (span2 > span)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be doing this :)

Your better option is to create a wrapper around the module. And inject your wrapper in the controller. That way you can mock the wrapper in your test.

```
public interface IAuthModule
{
   void WriteSessionTokenToCookie(Token sessionToken);
}

public class MyAuthModuleWrapper : IAuthModule
{
   public void WriteSessionTokenToCookie(Token sessionToken)
   {
       FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
   }
}
```

Then, if you are not using IoC container to wire up your app, you can use the poor's man version for your controller (I strongly recommend using IoC):

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   private readonly IAuthModule _authModule;

   public MyController() : this(new MyAuthModuleWrapper()){}

   public MyController(IAuthModule authModule)
   {
      _authModule = authModule;
   }

   public ActionResult MyTestAction(string data)
   {
        // ... do whatever is here
        var sessionToken = CreateSessionSecurityToken(CreatePrincipal(claims.ToList()), isPersistent);
        _authModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
        // ... do whatever else
   }
}
```

Then, in your tests you can use any mocking framework, or if you don't want that, you can create your own stub for IAuthToken, which behaves like you would like it to behave, and use that to construct your controller.

And ... you are all set. You can test your controller without depending on the registration of that third-party module.

Comment: Actually the auth code was exactly what I was trying to test. I already have a wrapper as you mentioned to make a pure UT for the controller. So in order to test the auth module I wanted to make sort of a integration test when bumped into my problem described in the question.

Comment: W/o seeing what the module implementation is, it's hard to tell. Still, why do you need to load it? Can't it be unit tested in isolation?

Comment: Well that was my first idea but no could not find a way. See my edit, added the implementation. If you have any ideas to test it in isolation would be exceptional.